# Python post requests - web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I am trying to access some data for web scraping. However I got stuck when reaching a point of extracting a graph from this [site](https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/842107/gabather) where i want to edit the data-timeperiod observed in the code below. Is there any way of extracting or changing this snippet from having data-timeperiod="today" active into data-timeperiod="week"?

For some extra information I have tried accessing the network tab in chrome to change this through a post request but each time I get denied access.

```
<div class="fLeft">
    <ul class="chartsTimeperiod cleanList floatList clearFix buttonPane">
        <li class="active">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="today" class="active default">
                    1 d.</a>
            </li>
        <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="week" class="">
                    1 v.</a>
            </li>
        <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="month" class="">
                    1 mån.</a>
            </li>
        <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="three_months" class="">
                    3 mån.</a>
            </li>
        <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="this_year" class="">
                    i år</a>
            </li>
        <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="year" class="">
                    1 år</a>
            </li>
        <li class="last">
                <a href="#" data-timeperiod="three_years" class="">
                    3 år</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I can see through the Network tab that there is a request payload containing following data. Is this something I should use in order to access the data or am I on the wrong track?

```
{"orderbookId":842107,"chartType":"AREA","widthOfPlotContainer":558,"chartResolution":"MINUTE","navigator":true,"percentage":false,"volume":false,"owners":false,"timePeriod":"week","ta":[],"compareIds":[19002]}
```

**Question 2 - Example:**
Based on [this](https://www.avanza.se/placera/forum/start.html?)

```
<form method="get" class="forumPagerForm">
        <label for="pageSizeSelect" class="fLeft marginTop5px">Visa antal inlägg:</label> 
        <select id="pageSizeSelect" class="pageSizeSelect">
            <option >15</option>
            <option >25</option>
            <option >50</option>
            <option >75</option>
            <option >100</option>
            <option selected="selected">200</option>
        </select>

        
    </form>
```

Comment: On Q2: Yoo need to send post to https://www.avanza.se/forum/user-preferences/posts-per-page i think

Comment: @UWTDTV Where did you find that url?

Comment: It is the first request after you have changed value.
https://i.ibb.co/Qf7t4jN/post.png

Comment: @UWTDTV When I try to first get the forum page and then do a Post request I get a 500 Server Error. I might do something wrong, but trying to validate through Postman but so far no success.

Comment: I get 204 from the post. But i don't tried to parse some info. https://i.ibb.co/W05dbzX/post.png

Comment: @UWTDTV What program did you do it through? Did you test with python as well? Maybe I am just doing a small error which causes problem for me?

Comment: The post request i made with python yes

Comment: Then it is really weird that it doesnt work for me.. And you dont supply the post with a payload (janson)?

Comment: If you look in the image i sent in the comment i send data={'posts': 50} in the post

Comment: Men skulle selenium kanske passa dig bättre @Fredrik?

Comment: @UWTDTV Failed on the payload, after fixing that it all seems to work! Since performance is on high key selenium is not really an option. With the amount of data I have it takes at least >2h in order to scrape 100000 data points without concurrency.

Comment: It was just a suggestion if you did not succeed with requests

Comment: @UWTDTV Understandable but I did a small error, a little new on the post part for requests but now it works, thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem @Fredrik

Comment: @UWTDTV Sorry to bother you again but after some debugging yesterday I realised that even if the data from the post got placed into the cookies the data that I wanted to take did not appear with the get text. After the get the content is still limited on 15 even if the posts is set to 200.

Comment: Ok... It is hard to give some advice without more research but maybe it is some header thing or some other parameters that you need to provide in next get request

Comment: @UWTDTV Could be, I will keep trying but it is weird that the session isnt taking care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests

janson = {
    "orderbookId": '842107',
    "chartType": "AREA",
    "widthOfPlotContainer": '558',
    "chartResolution": "MINUTE",
    "navigator": 'true',
    "percentage": 'false',
    "volume": 'false',
    "owners": 'false',
    "timePeriod": "week",
    "ta": [],
    "compareIds": ['19002']
}
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/842107/gabather')
p = s.post('https://www.avanza.se/ab/component/highstockchart/getchart/orderbook', json=janson)
print(p)
```

And after that scrape from variable **p**

Comment: Wow! This really did the thing! Thank you very much!

Comment: Det va så lite så @Fredrik

Comment: Om du har tid, får jag ställa en följdfråga? Om jag vill genomföra en post request mot en form som innehåller en select option med 4 alternativ varav den uppdateras när användaren klickar på ett nytt alternativ. Är det möjligt att skicka en request för att byta option och få sidan att uppdateras?

Comment: Inte helt säker på vad du menar. Du vill byta till låt oss säga månad eller år typ?

Comment: Uppdaterade frågan med ett exempel på data som finns samt en läk om du vill se innehållet också.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the points from the graph, yes? If you change the graph resolution - from let's say "week" to "month" - and look at the network traffic logger, you can see that the browser makes an HTTP POST request to `https://www.avanza.se/ab/component/highstockchart/getchart/orderbook`.

Simply imitate that request. Here, the graph resolution is set to `"week"`, but you should be able to change it to `"month"`, etc. Then I make the request and print the first ten points:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://www.avanza.se/ab/component/highstockchart/getchart/orderbook"

    data = {
        "chartResolution": "MINUTE",
        "chartType": "AREA",
        "compareIds": [19002],
        "navigator": True,
        "orderbookId": 842107,
        "owners": False,
        "percentage": False,
        "ta": [],
        "timePeriod": "week",
        "volume": False,
        "widthOfPlotContainer": 558
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    response.raise_for_status()

    data = response.json()

    for y, x in data["dataPoints"][0:10]:
        print(x, y)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
None 1594103400000
8.36 1594105200000
8.4 1594107000000
8.26 1594108800000
8.3 1594110600000
8.42 1594112400000
8.54 1594114200000
8.5 1594116000000
8.52 1594117800000
8.6 1594119600000
>>>
```